# HTML email is not working in table format

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am using tabular format in HTML email content but its not working to send email.
So can anyone let me know how to send table format email using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello please check your `wp_mail` return value.

```
$message = '<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Lead Person Name</td><td>'.$pname.'</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Tour Date</td><td>'.$date.'</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>No. Of Pax</td><td>'.$person.'</td>
                </tr>
          </table>';

$to = 'email@gmail.com';
$subject = 'HTML Formate mail';
$body = $message;
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$send_status = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

if($send_status)
 echo 'Mail Send Successfully';
else
 echo 'Something went wrong';
```

I hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $data = "<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>".$name."</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Lead Person Name</td><td>".$pname."</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Tour Date</td><td>".$date."</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>No. Of Pax</td><td>".$person."</td></tr>
            </table>";

$subject = 'HTML Formate mail';
$body = $data;
$headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';

wp_mail('email@gmail.com', $subject, $body, $headers );
```